# Merging Pandas Data frame based on multiple criteria and offsets

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows

```
              Date  Open  High   Low  Close  Volume  Open Interest  ContractYear Commodity Month_Code  ContractMonth Filename    CY
292715  03/04/1968  8.99  8.99  8.99   8.99       0              1          1969        ZL          F              1  ZL1969F  1968
292716  03/05/1968  9.02  9.02  8.96   8.96       1              2          1969        ZL          F              1  ZL1969F  1968
292717  03/06/1968  8.99  8.99  8.99   8.99       0              2          1969        ZL          F              1  ZL1969F  1968
292718  03/07/1968  9.01  9.01  9.01   9.01       0              2          1969        ZL          F              1  ZL1969F  1968
292719  03/08/1968  9.03  9.04  9.03   9.04       1              3          1969        ZL          F              1  ZL1969F  1968
292720  03/11/1968  9.03  9.04  9.01   9.01       9             10          1969        ZL          F              1  ZL1969F  1968
292721  03/12/1968  9.01  9.01  9.01   9.01       0             10          1969        ZL          F              1  ZL1969F  1968
292722  03/13/1968  9.00  9.00  9.00   9.00       0             10          1969        ZL          F              1  ZL1969F  1968
292723  03/14/1968  9.03  9.03  9.03   9.03       1             11          1969        ZL          F              1  ZL1969F  1968
292724  03/15/1968  8.97  9.01  8.97   9.01       1             12          1969        ZL          F              1  ZL1969F  1968
```

I am trying to extract values from the data frame and merge them as follows:

```
df1 = df[(df.Commodity == c) & (df.ContractMonth == n)]

df2 = df[(df.Commodity == c) & (df.ContractMonth == f) & (df.ContractYear == (df.ContractYear) +1)]

tempdf = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'inner', on = 'Date')
```

for df2 I am trying to offset the filter value by 1 or to the next year.  The above code/logic does not seem to work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `shift`, which creates a new series that is offset by a given number of rows:

```
df2 = df[(df.Commodity == c) & (df.ContractMonth == f) & (df.ContractYear == (df.ContractYear.shift(-1))]
```

Comment: That wont work since the number of rows are not constant.  For example one pair of data frames may be month 9 (current year) and month 3 (following year) and another might be month 7 and 9 of the same year.